# how to get "internal transactions" from transactions that have multiple erc-721 transfers in them? (web3 py)

Tags: erc-721, web3.py, ethereumj

Take a look at this transaction:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x542eb6e70c8122283fefc596f3fcc02a59579f5f43df7f3396f1b1ec72d03647#internal

There are multiple erc-721 token transfers happening in the same tx, how do I get hold of all these transfers and their individual eth prices? e.g. the total eth of the whole tx is 5.52 eth but I need 5.0 eth price for the first transfer

Answer (score 0):

when it is your tx, you can use `w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)`
and when you look at the tx receipt you may see the 'logs', in the log first
AttributeDict 'topics', that is what you are looking for. in the 3 HexBytes, last HexBytes is value, so when you decode Hexbytes to int that is what you are looking for

```
AttributeDict(
        {
            'blockHash': HexBytes('0xc690e3128af197e8080ece83d9f016a3d7c9a46c1a0e6102e44d4f827ecc885d'),
            'blockNumber': 99078956, 
            'contractAddress': None, 
            'cumulativeGasUsed': 377099, 
            'effectiveGasPrice': 250000000000, 
            'from': '0xdaf07D203C01467644e7305BE9caA6E9Fe12ac9a', 
            'gasUsed': 377099, 
            'logs': [
                AttributeDict(
                    {
                        'address': '0xceE8FAF64bB97a73bb51E115Aa89C17FfA8dD167', 
                        'blockHash': HexBytes('0xb6691fdf5e5422123dc7aedeb877c043ae2ff605dedda855923301c4d8f844a3'), 
                        'blockNumber': 99077559, 
                        'data': '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003b8b87c0', 
                        'logIndex': 35, 
                        'removed': False, 
                        'topics': [
                            HexBytes('0x8c5be1e5ebec7d5bd14f71427d1e84f3dd0314c0f7b2291e5b200ac8c7c3b925'), 
                            HexBytes('0x000000000000000000000000daf07d203c01467644e7305be9caa6e9fe12ac9a'), 
                            HexBytes('0x000000000000000000000000c6a2ad8cc6e4a7e08fc37cc5954be07d499e7654')
                        ], 
                        'transactionHash': HexBytes('0x58ab16aeee79dd43fa8d22801fd462c3c55a98464e7c6fe5ed8919f1b966aaf8'), 
                        'transactionIndex': 2
                    }
                ), 
                AttributeDict(
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).